# Rails 5 routing: Dynamic controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible for the route below to dynamically select different controllers or at least for a single controller to dynamically call another controller?

`get '*path' => 'routing#show`

For example:

```
/name-of-a-person => persons#show
/name-of-a-place => places#show
```

I recall reading something about Rails 5 that would enable this but I can't find it again to save my life. It's possible I imagined it.

Another options is to have a `RoutingController` that depending on which path is received will call different controllers.

The use case is I have URLs in the database with a type, and the controller depends on what type is the URL. I'm thinking something like this:

```
get '*path' do |params|
  url = Url.find_by!(path: params[:path])
  case url.type
  when 'person'
    'persons#show'
  when 'place'
    'places#show'
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, you can simply define your different routes as you already exemplified. Can you explain better the problem?

Comment: I cannot define them beforehand because I need an attribute from the database to find out which controller should handle the route, and I don't want to use a route prefix, so all routes will live under root. I updated my question with a more real example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post my second best solution so far; still waiting to see if anyone knows how to do this efficiently within the routes.

```
class RoutingController < ApplicationController
  def show
    url = Url.find_by!(path: params[:path])
    url.controller_class.dispatch('show', request, response)
  end
end
```

Hat tip to André for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could define one controller and inside its action make something like this:

```
def generic_show
  url = Url.find_by!(path: params[:path])
  case url.type
  when 'person'
    controller = PersonController.new
    controller.request = request
    controller.response = response
    controller.show
  when 'place'
    ...
  end
end
```

However, I would recommend you to move the code you want to reuse to other classes and use them in both controllers. It should be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, it's not about code reuse. I just navigated Rails source a bit and it seems your sample wouldn't work with Rails 5, but I found the `dispatch` method which should work, so thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to do it using advanced routing constraints.

From: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

> If you have a more advanced constraint, you can provide an object that responds to matches? that Rails should use. Let's say you wanted to route all users on a blacklist to the BlacklistController. You could do:

```
class BlacklistConstraint
  def initialize
    @ips = Blacklist.retrieve_ips
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '*path', to: 'blacklist#index',
    constraints: BlacklistConstraint.new
end
```

I don't think the Rails guide example is particularly good, because this problem could essentially be solved in your application controllers before_action.

In this example, the constraint is used for IP filtering, but you could also implement `matches?` to check if it's a person. I would imagine something like

```
def matches?(request)
  Person.where(slug: request.params[:path]).any?
end
```

And as such, the Rails router can decide whether or not to dispatch the request to the `persons#show` action.

Comment: I thought about that but I'd need a different route for each type of URL with its appropriate constraint so it would not be very efficient.

Comment: Why not? How many types do you need? What makes it inefficient by your definition?

Comment: Each constraint would have to query the database. Say the first one didn't match, then the next one has to make the same query too and so on. Rails query cache would probably help but still doesn't feel right.

Comment: Depends on your database latency, your type count and your implementation. If each query is 1 ms (realistically) and you have 10 types, it's 10 ms and therefore insignificant.

If you have many types (or latency) you can implement a more sophisticated constraint that builds an in-memory map of the slugs and shares the instance across requests and across routes.